# SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'for'.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Here I am getting error with this code. I want to print loop inside `dynamiHTML`. Any one can help me.?

```
function createDiv(data){
var dynamicHTML = '';
alert(data.res2.length);

        dynamicHTML += '<div id="'+ data.res2[i].Paper_Type +'" class="tabcontent" style="border:none;">'+
            for(var i=0; i<data.res2.length; i++){
            +'<div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">'+
                '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">'+ data.res2[i].Paper_Name +'</label>'+
                '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">'+
                    '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Go!</button>'+
                '</span>'+   
            '</div>'+ } +
        '</div>';
  $('div#tabs_data').append(dynamicHTML);
}
```

Comment: Ok you are right but I have not post my controller code here so..

Comment: You can not have a 'for' inside html code.

Comment: then what should be there.?

Comment: you can do this by separating the javascript code from your html.

Comment: sorry. Please write code with explaination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running for-loop while creating and concatenating html string literal may not be possible.

You can separate the funcanality

```
 function createDiv(data) {
      var dynamicHTML = '';
      var innerContent = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < data.res2.length; i++) {
        innerContent += '<div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">' +
          '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +
          '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
          '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Go!</button>' +
          '</span>' +
          '</div>' +
      }

      dynamicHTML += '<div id="' + data.res2[i].Paper_Type + '" class="tabcontent" style="border:none;">' + innerContent + '</div>';
      $('div#tabs_data').append(dynamicHTML);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function createDiv(data) {
    var dynamicHTML = '';
    alert(data.res2.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.res2.length; i++) {
        dynamicHTML += '<div id="' + data.res2[i].Paper_Type + '" class="tabcontent" style="border:none;">' +
                '<div class="input-group" style="border-color:#3D8EB9; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #888888; margin-bottom: 3px; background-color: #fff;">' +
                    '<label style="padding:10px 10px;">' + data.res2[i].Paper_Name + '</label>' +
                    '<span class="input-group-btn" style="padding-top:10px;">' +
                        '<button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Go!</button>' +
                    '</span>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>';
    }
    $('div#tabs_data').append(dynamicHTML);
}
```

Comment: what do you change in above code in my code comperision.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( window ).load(function() {
  var html = "";
  var data = [];
  var i=0;
  while(i<10){
    data[i]="hello user_"+i;
    html = html+"<div id = \""+i+"\">";
    html = html+data[i];
    html = html+"</div>";
    i++;
  }
 $('#container').append(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "container">
</div>
```

A simple example for you to follow.

As you can see, I split html and javascript. Html code turns red and javascript gets other colors.

The way I get this is through the concatenation of stirng.

When you use "" in your string. You have to do this:

```
html <div = id = \" " + i + "\">";
```